# Нужна запятая перед "что" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, союзные-слова

Он сказал ему(,) что нужно сделать к понедельнику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он сказал ему, **что** нужно сделать к понедельнику.*

Запятая нужна, так как это сложное предложение.
В главной части есть подлежащее (***он***) и сказуемое (***сказал***). Вторая часть содержит только сказуемое (***нужно сделать***), является [безличным предложением](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), зависит от главного и присоединяется к нему с помощью союзного слова [***что***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x).

*И тогда я сажусь и думаю, что нужно сделать.

Но он никак не мог понять, что нужно сделать.

Если бы только она знала, что нужно сделать, чтобы их переубедить!

Игорь Васильевич говорит, что нужно сделать.

Неужели настолько сложно понять, что нужно сделать?*